# Normal form of boolean expressions linear/affine w.r.t. conjunction and disjunction

Tags: boolean-algebras, normalization

$\DeclareMathOperator\Bool{Bool}$I am interested in boolean expressions that are linear/affine in the following sense.

Let $\Bool(X)$ be the free boolean algebra over the set $X$.
We can consider the subset $\Bool^\#(X)$ consisting of those elements that can be expressed using 0, 1, conjunction ($\land$), disjunction ($\lor$) and negation ($\lnot$) and using every "variable" from $X$ exactly / at most once.

I think I can prove that we can compute normal forms for such expressions while preserving the affine property (unlike the conjunctive/disjunctive normal form) as follows:

- push all negations down to the leaves of the syntax tree
- eliminate negations of constants
- eliminate double negations
- eliminate conjunctions/disjunctions with constants
- remove parentheses of nested conjunctions / nested disjunctions.

However, I wonder if anyone else has studied such expressions and their normal forms, and under what name. (It seems that 'linear boolean function' usually refers to linear maps between vector spaces over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: would this essentially amount to studying the "linear" subtheory of the theory of boolean algebras? that leads to the question if every algebraic theory has a "greatest linear subtheory", which could be abstractly restated as asking if the inclusion of cartesian into symmetric operads has a right adjoint ...

Comment: I'm not sure about the adjoint formulation. But in any case: note that the linearization depends on the presentation, e.g. it would be different if we also consider xor a primitive operation on boolean algebras.

Comment: Interesting, I guess that means that there isn't an adjoint as that would give a representation independent linearization